# How to add record (call a method) without a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a standard model/table with just a few fields that has a controller and the basic scaffolded views associated(step).  This is independent of the applicationuser.  I also have a relational table in the middle (userstep).  I'm trying to add a method in the step controller that is called based on a click within the view and this method should create a userstep record based on the current information(current user, current step).  I hope this makes sense because it's driving me crazy.  This is my method within the stepcontroller.

```
public ActionResult Create(UserStep userStep)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            UserStep userstep = new UserStep();
            userstep.StepID = db.Steps.Find(id);
            userstep.UserId = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());


            db.UserSteps.Add(userStep);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

Now I realize this may be completely wrong because I basically took the manual create function from the userstep views which had dropdowns for both user and step.

I will then be calling this from the step details screen like this.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Create", "Step")" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal" data-thevideo="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.URL)">
      <div class="text-center">Play Now</div>
</a>
```

I assume it's obvious I'm a little lost, but I guess I have two questions.

- What is wrong with my method if I don't need a view, but instead just the record to be created?
- How do I grab the current step and current user if the method is about userstep?

**Update**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Create(UserStep userStep)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            UserStep userstep = new UserStep();
            userstep.StepID = db.Steps.Find(id);
            userstep.UserId = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());


            db.UserSteps.Add(userStep);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

I am now getting conversion errors with can't convert to int for stepid and can't convert to string for userid, however I'm not sure how to convert these.

Here are my models.

*Step*

```
public class Step
{
    [Display(Name = "Step #")]
    public int StepID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [StringLength(200, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string URL { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserStep> UserSteps { get; set; }
}
```

*UserStep*

```
public class UserStep
{
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public int UserStepID { get; set; }
    public int StepID { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual Step Step { get; set; }


}
```

ApplicationUser

```
    ....other areas

    public virtual ICollection<UserStep> UserSteps { get; set; }
```

I apologize for asking for some much detail, but this one area seems so important to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning `ActionResult`, you can create a function that returns `JsonResult`, etc. Or even better, you can create and use a WebApi Controller (it scaffolds some CRUD functions for you if you choose to).

Then, in the client side, you use some Ajax call (using jQuery or any js framework) to access your server side method and reflect the returned (json) results in your html (DOM). There are several client side (js) frameworks such as angular, etc that will help you to achieve this behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I'm fairly new to the mvc world and don't yet know how to use your ideas of a jsonresult instead or a webapi.  Is there not a way to do this through a controller method?  I have adjusted my controller above believing my approach is still possible.

Comment: Yes, if the same method returns json (`JsonResult`) instead of ActionResult and not return View, you can achieve that. Returning a view is saying to client browser to update the whole page again..